# groupby to find row with max value is converting object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I want to groupby two variables ['CIN','calendar'] and return the row of that group where the column MCelig is the largest in that specific group.  It is likely that multiple rows will have the max value, but i only want one row.

for example:

```
  AidCode CIN  MCelig   calendar
0    None  1e       1 2014-03-08
1      01  1e       2 2014-03-08
2      01  1e       3 2014-05-08
3    None  2e       4 2014-06-08
4      01  2e       5 2014-06-08
```

Since the first two rows are a group, I want the row where MCelig =2.
I came up with this line

```
test=dfx.groupby(['CIN','calendar'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.ix[x.MCelig.idxmax()])
```

and it seemed to work, except when i have all 'None' or 'np.nan' for all values in a group for a column, that column is converted to a datetime!  see the example below and watch AidCode go from an object to a date.

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
d = {'CIN' : pd.Series(['1e','1e','1e','2e','2e']),
'AidCode' : pd.Series([np.nan,'01','01',np.nan,'01']),
'calendar' : pd.Series([DT.datetime(2014, 3, 8), DT.datetime(2014, 3, 8),DT.datetime(2014, 5, 8),DT.datetime(2014, 6, 8),DT.datetime(2014, 6, 8)]),
'MCelig' : pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])}
dfx=pd.DataFrame(d)
#testing whether it was just the np.nan that was the problem, it isn't
#dfx = dfx.where((pd.notnull(dfx)), None)
test=dfx.groupby(['CIN','calendar'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.ix[x.MCelig.idxmax()])
```

output

```
Out[820]: 
                  AidCode CIN  MCelig   calendar
CIN calendar                                    
1e  2014-03-08 2015-01-01  1e       2 2014-03-08
    2014-05-08 2015-01-01  1e       3 2014-05-08
2e  2014-06-08 2015-01-01  2e       5 2014-06-08
```

**UPDATE:**

just figured out this simple solution

```
x=dfx.sort(['CIN','calendar',"MCelig"]).groupby(["CIN",'calendar'], as_index=False).last();x
```

since it works, i think I chose it for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas attempts to be extra helpful by recognizing columns that look like dates and converting the column to datetime64 dtype. It's being overly aggressive here.

A workaround would be to use `transform` to generate *a boolean mask* for each group which selects maximum rows:

```
def onemax(x):
    mask = np.zeros(len(x), dtype='bool')
    idx = np.argmax(x.values)
    mask[idx] = 1
    return mask

dfx.loc[dfx.groupby(['CIN','calendar'])['MCelig'].transform(onemax).astype(bool)]
```

yields

```
  AidCode CIN  MCelig   calendar
1      01  1e       2 2014-03-08
2      01  1e       3 2014-05-08
4      01  2e       5 2014-06-08
```

---

Technical detail: When groupby-apply is used, when the individual DataFrames (returned by the applied function) are glued back together into one DataFrame, Pandas tries to guess if columns
with object dtype are date-like objects, and if so, [convert the column to
an actual date dtype](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2914). If the values are strings, it tries to parse them as
dates using `dateutil.parser`:

For better or for worse, `dateutil.parser` interprets `'01'` as a date:

```
In [37]: import dateutil.parser as DP

In [38]: DP.parse('01')
Out[38]: datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

This causes Pandas to attempt to convert the entire AidCode column into dates. Since no error occurs, it thinks it just helped you out :)

Comment: you're a genius!  I've been messing with this for days.  Thank you.

Comment: When i run this on my actual data, i'm getting "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided", and i'm not sure how to investigate this issue?  ever see that?  why do i need the 'astype(bool)?

Comment: Try changing `return mask` to `return mask.values` in the `onemax` function. This will return a NumPy array instead of a Series. Since the NumPy array has no index, there should be no "Unalignable boolean Series" problem. That *might* solve the problem.

Comment: The `astype(bool)` is needed because the `transform` method converts the boolean values returned by `onemax` to ints. To use the values as a boolean mask, we need to re-convert them to bools. That seems ugly to me, but I haven't investigated why Pandas chooses to do this.

Comment: agreed, and thanks again.  extremely helpful and informative.